# Are there official Typescript type definitions for OpenAPI 3?

Tags: typescript, openapi, openapi-generator

I've found https://github.com/metadevpro/openapi3-ts/blob/master/src/model/OpenApi.ts which is a version of Typescript definitions for OpenAPI 3.x, but I'm failing to find an official (aka DefinitelyTyped) type definition file for OAS 3.

Is there one?

TIA

Comment: This isn't official, but it looks like it has OpenAPI 2 and 3 definitions
https://github.com/kogosoftwarellc/open-api/tree/master/packages/openapi-types

Comment: Thanks @Graham. I found that one after posting my question, but so far the node module for `openapi3-ts` is meeting my needs. About to do a more ambitious project with it right now, so I may be looking for something else shortly ;)

Answer (score 5):

There's a lib openapi-types, which is from openAPI, it official enough for me.
lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-types

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more [@fosfad/openapi-typescript-definitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fosfad/openapi-typescript-definitions). Decent I guess but not very comprehensive.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid there is no official TS definition, only the documents describing the types.

[OAI GitHub](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/tree/master/versions) (all versions)

[swagger.io](https://swagger.io/specification/) (latest)

---

The one you mentioned [openapi3-ts](https://github.com/metadevpro/openapi3-ts/blob/master/src/model/OpenApi.ts) seems like the most complete and update typescript definition available